# Sharepoint 2013 - Lookup item not working (Does not display value)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Lookup value column in SharePoint 2013, which is linked to another field in the same list.

When I add a "New Item", this field is not showing any value whereas the field it's referring to on the same list does have a value.

Please note I'm looking for a solution/configuration that doesn't involve any code-related fix.

Comment: Your words are clear, but I'm having trouble understanding the problem. Can you post a screenshot or two that demonstrate the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct solution, but when i tried the same. I could not add when I add a "New Item", but I could edit the same and add the lookup value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking up the value of a different column in the same list, you should just use a calculated column instead of lookup.

Lookups should look to a seperate list entirely. When you select Calculated Column as the type, you should see the formula settings below. You can then select the column name you want from the list on the right.